# Using SVN or source control inside eclipse for beginners

Tags: eclipse, svn

I am now learning the basics of source control using tortoise SVN. I want to use SVN instead of the (manually made) multiple copies of my code. I need your help with some questions-

1 - Is it possible to do SVN inside eclipse itself or maybe integrate eclipse with some SVN software ? If yes, would this be a good approach ?

2- Can the USE of SVN cause new errors or issues besides the many compiler errors that one already has to deal with ?

3- Which is better Tortoise SVN or Tortoise HG ?

Thanks.

Comment: If you're new to SVN, definitely familiarize yourself with the SVN red book (http://svnbook.red-bean.com/). It's like the Bible for SVN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) There are two Eclipse integrations for SVN: [Subversive](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/) and [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org). I recently used Subversive but both are more or less equal and work quite well.

2) If you use it correctly, you shouldn't have to deal with more errors. But using a version control system like Subversion is a bit more complicated than not using one :-)

3) Tortoise SVN is used to work with the Subversion repositories while Tortoise HG is used for [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com) repositories. These are two different things! If you want to work with Subversion you can not use Tortoise HG.

Comment: what is the difference between Subversion repositories and Mercurial repositories ?

Comment: These are just two different products trying to solve the same problem, i.e. versioning your files.

Comment: BTW: If you never used a version control system before, you could also start learning [GIT](http://git-scm.com). The learning curve is a bit longer than with Subversion but GIT is becoming more and more popular while Subversion is getting older and older.

Before you asked about Mercurial. Mercurial uses exactly the same concepts than GIT and works very similar.

Comment: "If you use it correctly, you shouldn't have to deal with more errors." - that whole "use it correctly" part usually takes a few years to learn, though :)

Comment: @Alex- :( Years ??? I wanted something that is very easy to begin with...like maybe hours to a few days to learn the basics.

Comment: @StefanFerstl - It seems that GIT and Mercurial are quite similar. Then why should one choose one tool over the other ?

Comment: @sweetdreams You can definitely learn the basics in a few days. But there are intricacies in any version control system that take a long time to master.

Comment: @sweetdreams Asking "why Git or Mercurial" is a whole question unto itself and is best not delved into here. There are passionate advocates of each one, and many places on the internet where you can go to read the relative merits of each.

Comment: @sweetdreams I agree with Alex. When it comes to decide between Mercurial and GIT, the discussion mostly gets dogmatic. I like GIT very much, especially because of https://github.com . But technically, they do the very same thing. I also liked Subversion many years ago. But it has definitely some disadvantages like the centralized repository. It's just not state of the art anymore (my opinion).